# Xcode shortcut to create method definition

Tags: ios, eclipse, xcode, xcode5

In eclipse, I can use methods before I create their definitions as eclipse will give me to option to create the definition once I hover over the method; the same is true for using classes before creating their definitions. Is there something similar in Xcode? Some kind of short cut that will allow me to create method definitions? so that if I use

```
[self myMethod:someString];
```

Then I can have Xcode create the signature for me.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks its not work like eclipse but you can use Code snippet library (templates) from right side bottom of xCode. It is drag and drop feature.